# Toggle Divs but show only one at once

Tags: jquery, toggle

I have searched Stackoverflow but wasnt able to find any solution for this particular case.

Here is my code:

[JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yd2ysnLx/28/)

```
<div class="wpgtoggle">
    <div class="toggleheader" data-toggle="#toggle1">This is header</div>
    <div class="toggleclose">X</div>
    <div id="toggle1" class="togglecontent">
This is content
    </div>
</div>

<div class="wpgtoggle">
    <div class="toggleclose" id="toggle2">X</div>
    <div class="toggleheader" data-toggle="#toggle2">This is header</div>
    <div id="toggle2"  class="togglecontent">This is content</div>
</div>

<div class="wpgtoggle">
    <div class="toggleclose" id="toggle3">X</div>
    <div class="toggleheader"  data-toggle="#toggle3">This is header</div>
    <div id="toggle3"  class="togglecontent">This is content</div>
</div>
```

Functionality I want to achieve is just like this: [Link](http://www.minzgmbh.de/team/)

If no close button then yes my current code works fine but thing is that my client need extra "close" button too like example I have given above.

How can I achieve this?

Regards.

Comment: Oh, this is just an accordion. There are plenty of plugins out there for this, starting with jQueryUI's solution.

Comment: Yes I already checked this one but its not what I need.. please check that I also need a "close" button like example I have added. http://www.minzgmbh.de/team/

Comment: As I said, there are _plenty_ accordions plugins around :)

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    <style>
    .wpgtoggle {border:1px solid #ccc; padding:10px; margin-bottom: 20px;}
    .togglecontent {display:none;}
    .toggleclose {font-size:20px; position: absolute; color:red; right:0;}
    </style>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    $(function(){
        $("div[data-toggle]").on("click", function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();  // prevent navigating
            $(".togglecontent").slideUp();
            var selector = $(this).data("toggle");  // get corresponding element
            $(selector).slideToggle();
        });
        $( ".toggleclose" ).click(function() {
            $($(this).data("toggleclose")).slideUp("slow");
        });
    });
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="wpgtoggle">
            <div class="toggleheader" data-toggle="#toggle1">This is header</div>
            <div class="toggleclose" data-toggleclose="#toggle1">X</div>
            <div id="toggle1" class="togglecontent">This is content</div>
        </div>
        <div class="wpgtoggle">
            <div class="toggleclose" data-toggleclose="#toggle2">X</div>
            <div class="toggleheader" data-toggle="#toggle2">This is header</div>
            <div id="toggle2"  class="togglecontent">This is content</div>
        </div>
        <div class="wpgtoggle">
            <div class="toggleclose" data-toggleclose="#toggle3">X</div>
            <div class="toggleheader"  data-toggle="#toggle3">This is header</div>
            <div id="toggle3"  class="togglecontent">This is content</div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```